# Changing a field in multiple rows in one task, in a Laravel Nova application

Tags: laravel-nova

I have a list of **UserTasks** (model/resource) with a **User** (model/resource) set as owner (field). The list is made from a Nova/Ressource class.

1. I can select many rows in the list. (no problem - Nova out of the box)
2. The select rows/models can be handled with an Action. (no problem)
3. I want to change all the owner fields to a new user that I pick from a list. How do I do that?

I can use an Action to redirect the selected models to a new page.

But how do I create a Nova page with 2 different models/resources. The selected **UserTasks** and a list of **users**, from where I can pick the new owner?

Or should I use a different approach to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question but out-of-the-box Nova doesn't have a system that allows you to make a dedicated page to link a resource to other n resources.

One possible solution is this:

`php artisan nova:action ActionName`

**File: YourNovaResource.php, like Task.php**

```
use App\Nova\Actions\ActionName;

...

public function actions(Request $request)
{
    return [
        new ActionName
    ];
}
```

**File: ActionName.php**

```
public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
{
    foreach ($models as $model) {
        $model->user_id = $fields->user_id;
    }
}

public function fields()
{
    $users = User::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
    return [
        Select::make('New owner', 'user_id')
            ->options($users),
    ];
}
```

By doing so you can select the rows to which you want to assign a new owner by taking it from the users list.

**Note**: If you don't like this solution and want to have a dedicated page, you could create a [Nova custom tool](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/tools.html), *perhaps having a table on the left with the users and on the right with the tasks to be associated*.